# Where should I start to debug when Make throws a particular error

Tags: makefile

My knowledge of Make is small. I have been told that everything you put after make (that does not contain "-") is a target.
Well a building process I have is failing.
First there is a line

```
make path/to/configuration_file
```

`configuration_file` is not a target. It is a autogenerated configuration file buried inside the directory structure ("path/to") that is of the form

```
#
# Boot Configuration
#

#
# DRAM Component
#
CONFIG_DRAM_TYPE_LPDDR4=y
# CONFIG_DRAM_TYPE_DDR4 is not set
CONFIG_DDR_SIZE=0x80000000

#
# Boot Device
#
# CONFIG_ENABLE_EMMC_BOOT is not set
# CONFIG_ENABLE_NAND_BOOT is not set
CONFIG_ENABLE_SPINAND_BOOT=y
# CONFIG_ENABLE_SPINOR_BOOT is not set
CONFIG_EMMC_ACCESS_8BIT=y
# CONFIG_EMMC_ACCESS_4BIT is not set
# CONFIG_EMMC_ACCESS_1BIT is not set
```

so I cannot understand how this is a target. For reference, when I run make there is a Makefile but this Makefile does not reference this file.

Still this line is going well.
The path where it fails says

```
make diags
```

and I have verified there is no "diags" target.

I will print here the error file that can give us more info of what is happening

```
GEN cortex_a/output/Makefile
Init diag test "orc_scheduler" ...
remoteconfig: Failed to generate configure in cortex_a/soc/visio/tests/orc_scheduler!
Makefile:11 recipe for target 'orc_scheduler-init' failed
make[10]: *** [orc_scheduler-init] Error 25
```

At least what I would like to know is how to interpret this error message. I don't know what the "11" or the "10" or the "25" refers to.

Comment: What's your actual `Makefile` look like? When you run `make path/to/configuration_file`, `path/to/configuartion_file` is the target. Based on your error message, I suspect there is a recursive call to `make` or some attempt to run a second `Makefile` whose `orc_scheduler-init` target fails.

Answer (score 0):

make is fundamentally a tool for automatically running commands in the right order so you don't have to type them in yourself.  So all the commands make runs are commands that you could just type into your shell prompt.  And all the errors that those commands generate are the same ones that you would see if you typed the command yourself.  So, looking at make to try to understand those errors is looking in the wrong place: you have to look at the documentation for whatever command was invoked.

A "target" is just a file that make knows how to build.  The fact that when you typed `make <somefile>` is didn't give you an error that it doesn't know how to build `<somefile>`, means that `<somefile>` is a target as far as your makefiles are concerned.

The error message `Makefile:11:` simply refers to the filename `Makefile`, line 11, which is where the command that make ran, that failed, can be found.  But this likely won't help you solve the problem of why the command failed (unless the problem is you invoked it with the wrong arguments and you need to adjust the makefile to specify different arguments).

The command that failed generated the message:

```
remoteconfig: Failed to generate configure in cortex_a/soc/visio/tests/orc_scheduler!
```

I don't know what that means, but it's not related to make.  You'll need to find out what this `remoteconfig` command is, what it does, and why it failed.  It's unfortunate that it doesn't show any better error message as to *why* it failed to "generate configure", but again there's nothing make can do about that.

If you want to learn more about make you can look at the [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Overview.html) (note, GNU make is only one implementation of make; there are others and they are fundamentally the same but different in details).